# Non-normalised Bargmann Coherent States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-optics, coherent-states

Currently, I am reading a paper which involves non-normalised [Bargmann coherent states](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=bargmann+coherent+state) as my basis. I am interested in knowing how the creation and annihilation operator acts on these coherent states. I have looked it up in books but haven't found the action of creation and annihilation operators on these states.

Comment: Pretty sure you can find this in Gardiner & Zoller.

Comment: What is a "Bargmann coherent state"?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch By Bargmann coherent states, I mean coherent states in Bargmann representation

Comment: If they are just coherent states, creation and annihilation operators will act like they act on any coherent state!  Why is the Bargmann representation relevant?

Comment: @Mark Mitchinson Thanks for the book. The book has a description of expressing an operator in  Bargmann representation of coherent states(Page 101). However, it does not have the exact expression of the creation or annihilation operator acting on some Bargmann coherent states. If you find it, please let me know.

Comment: @Norbert Schuch Actually the way creation and annihilation operator acts on coherent states depends on the form of coherent states we use. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%E2%80%93Bargmann_space] for the Bargmann coherent states.

Comment: @MarkMitchison I was able to derive the action of creation and annihilation operator acting on coherent states for the ones given in link[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Thermal_coherent_state]. However, in [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal%E2%80%93Bargmann_space] there is an expression for the Bargmann coherent states. Is it the correct form? If yes how is this the correct form?

Comment: there’s actually a coherent state tag on this site.  Why not start there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for lack of basic research on this site.